# Building a customized user store manager for WSO2

Tags: java, wso2, osgi, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure WSO2 to authenticate a user via LDAP, but then augment the user with attributes stored elsewhere (exploring some legacy integration-type scenarios, so moving everything to LDAP really isn't in the cards).

The user attribute documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Managing+User+Attributes#ManagingUserAttributes-Writingcustomattributes) indicates that this is best accomplished by writing a custom user store and https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager#WritingaCustomUserStoreManager-ImplementingacustomJDBCuserstoremanager lists out `AbstractUserStoreManager` as the class to extend and work with (though, in all probability, we would extend a subsclass).

The problem I am running into as I am rummaging through the WSO2 IS code on github is that I cannot seem to find a class by this name or methods by the names mentioned in the documentation. My guess would be that sometime between 4.4-ish and present (5.6 being the version I downloaded as an MSI) that the integration point changed. Has it changed? If not, where should I be looking for the classes to extend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look in the wso2-carbon-kernal for the classes. For IS 5.6 try looking in the 4.4.x branch of carbon-kernel

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core

Answer (score 0):

If you are authenticating with LDAP, I suggest you to extend the `ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager` and just overwrite the getUserProperties method (or something like that, I don't recall the method name now)

Answer (score 0):

Carbon-kernel **v4.4.32** is used for WSO2 IS 5.6.0 [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.6.0/pom.xml#L1810). You can refer the existing implementations from here [[2]](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap)[[3]](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc) to get an idea.

[1](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.6.0/pom.xml#L1810) https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.6.0/pom.xml#L1810
[2](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap) https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap
[3](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc) https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.32/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc